# How to list installed package and its details on ubuntu?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am new to ubuntu and trying to find out the way to list all installed packages and its details like version, release, install time, category on Ubuntu. Found that following commands will help me get some of this information:

1) `dpkg -l`

2) `dpkg-query -W -f='${PackageSpec}\t${version}\t${Description}\n'`

Unlike Redhat the install time and category information is missing in this. Can anyone know of a way to retrieve these details?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Simple and elegant:

```
sudo dpkg -l | more
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -l | less
```

If you want to get the description of some specific packages say `firefox`:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep firefox
```

Here is my output of:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | more
 Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                        Version                                 Description
+++-===========================================-=======================================-==============================================================
================
ii  accountsservice                             0.6.15-2ubuntu9.4                       query and manipulate user account information
ii  acl                                         2.2.51-5ubuntu1                         Access control list utilities
ii  acpi-support                                0.140                                   scripts for handling many ACPI events
ii  acpid                                       1:2.0.10-1ubuntu3                       Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon
ii  activity-log-manager-common                 0.9.4-0ubuntu3.2                        blacklist configuration for Zeitgeist (assets)
ii  activity-log-manager-control-center         0.9.4-0ubuntu3.2                        blacklist configuration for Zeitgeist (control center integrat
ion)
ii  adduser                                     3.113ubuntu2                            add and remove users and groups
ii  adium-theme-ubuntu                          0.3.2-0ubuntu1                          Adium message style for Ubuntu
ii  aisleriot                                   1:3.2.3.2-0ubuntu1                      Solitaire card games
ii  akonadi-backend-mysql                       1.7.2-0ubuntu1                          MySQL storage backend for Akonadi
ii  akonadi-server                              1.7.2-0ubuntu1                          Akonadi PIM storage service
ii  alacarte                                    0.13.2-2ubuntu4                         easy GNOME menu editing tool
ii  alsa-base                                   1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                  1.0.25-1ubuntu5                         Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  anacron                                     2.3-14ubuntu1                           cron-like program that doesn't go by time
ii  apg                                         2.2.3.dfsg.1-2                          Automated Password Generator - Standalone version
ii  app-install-data                            0.12.04.4                               Ubuntu applications (data files)
ii  app-install-data-partner                    12.12.04.1                              Application Installer (data files for partner applications/rep
ositories)
ii  apparmor                                    2.7.102-0ubuntu3.7                      User-space parser utility for AppArmor
ii  appmenu-gtk                                 0.3.92-0ubuntu1.1                       Export GTK menus over DBus
ii  appmenu-gtk3                                0.3.92-0ubuntu1.1                       Export GTK menus over DBus
ii  appmenu-qt                                  0.2.6-0ubuntu1                          appmenu support for Qt
ii  apport                                      2.0.1-0ubuntu17.1                       automatically generate crash reports for debugging
ii  apport-gtk                                  2.0.1-0ubuntu17.1                       GTK+ frontend for the apport crash report system
ii  apport-symptoms                             0.16.1                                  symptom scripts for apport
ii  apt                                         0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.7                  commandline package manager
ii  apt-transport-https                         0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.7                  https download transport for APT
ii  apt-utils                                   0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.7                  package managment related utility programs
--More--
```

#### To get the date and time of packages being installed

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep " install "
```

To get for specific package:

```
$cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep " install " | grep banshee
2013-12-12 12:51:48 install banshee <none> 2.4.1-3ubuntu1~precise2
2013-12-12 12:51:51 install banshee-extensions-common <none> 2.4.0-1ubuntu1
2013-12-12 12:51:51 install banshee-extension-radiostationfetcher <none> 2.4.0-    1ubuntu1
2013-12-12 12:51:51 install banshee-extension-soundmenu <none> 2.4.1-3ubuntu1~precise2
```

#### To get the section

```
$apt-cache show firefox | grep Section
Section: web
```

[See Also: ListInstalledPackagesByDate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ListInstalledPackagesByDate?action=fullsearch&value=linkto%3A%22ListInstalledPackagesByDate%22&context=180)

Comment: I Had seen these two ways but was not sure if these are the consistent ways to use on all versions of Ubuntu. One more concern was if apt-cache reports in certain conditions only (like if caching is enabled). 

Can I rely on these commands to get the details?

Comment: It seems that apt cache can be deleted and that command won't return all the information. Correct me if I am wrong. Will dpkg --print-avail <package_name> help me get the same details if apt cache is deleted?

Comment: @user224730: I don't know how you'll delete `apt-cache`, but yes you are right. `dpkg --print-avail` will do the same job if you want to get the sufficient information. One thing you should note that `sudo apt-cache show` command always gives you some extra information. You can verify it by comparing these two commands output. 1.`sudo apt-cache show firefox | wc` and 2. `sudo dpkg --print-avail firefox | wc` You'll notice that **1st** command returns more number of lines, words and characters than the **2nd** one. Reply if you've still some doubts..

Comment: apt-get clean is the command I learned about which deletes the cache. I ran both the commands you mentioned about on my system and found that apt-cache show firefox | wc returned me some record, however dpkg --print-avail | wc did not. I checked if firefox is installed on my system by running dpkg -l | grep firefox and I got nothing. I ran the same commands for the package which is installed on the system and found that apt-cache show command also prints the information about the latest patch that is available for this package. That means, the package is the candidate for update.

Comment: Well, that takes me to the decision that dpkg --print-avail is the command I am looking for which gives me the actual information of the package level installed on the system.

Comment: @user1787572: Since your question has been solved, I suggest you to accept one of the answer in this post which best describes your problem. Accepting the answer will not only mark this post as solved, but also help others to get the answer for the same type of questions. :)

Answer (score 8):

`apt-cache showpkg <package>` will give you details about what package versions are available, forward and reverse dependencies etc.

`apt-cache show <package>` will provide description, category (Section) etc.

I'm not aware of a way to see at what time a package was installed.

Answer (score 4):

## Using apt

Another method to list the installed packages is:

```
apt list --installed
```

All the packages installed **manual** can be printed by

```
apt list --manual-installed
```

whereas **all versions** get listed by:

```
apt list --all-versions
```

These are very useful commands. For instance if you want to install local installed packages to another computer, you only have to do the following command

```
apt list --installed | awk -F/ -v ORS=" " 'NR>1 {print $1}' > apt_packages.txt
```

In case you only want to get manually installed packages, try this:

```
 apt list --manual-installed | awk -F/ -v ORS=" " 'NR>1 {print $1}' > apt_packages.txt
```

Now all your apt-packages are ready to install on another or new installed Ubuntu system.

```
sudo apt-get install < apt_packages.txt
```

### Detailed Description

If you want to know exactly **when**, **what** and **which** packages have been removed take a look in your

```
/var/log/apt
```

directory. E.g. search in the `history.log` files or  use **sed**, **awk**, **grep** or your favorite text-editor to search your history files.

Comment: Just to note that `apt list --manual-installed` does **NOT** just list things that _YOU_ have "manually" installed :-(

Answer (score 3):

> ### Now it is far easier to get the installation details of packages.

Here are the simple steps:

1. Copy and paste following script in a file and save it with any name say `pkgdetails`.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   #Get the details and section of installed packages
   # usage:
   # pkgdetails <pkgname1> <pkgname2>

   #first append all info from archived logs

   i=2
   mycount=$(ls -l /var/log/dpkg.log.*.gz | wc -l)
   nlogs=$(( $mycount + 1 ))

   while [ $i -le $nlogs ]
   do
   if [ -e /var/log/dpkg.log.$i.gz ]; then
   zcat /var/log/dpkg.log.$i.gz | grep "\ install\ " >> $HOME/pkgtmp.txt
   fi
   i=$(( $i+1 ))

   done

   #next append all info from unarchived logs

   i=1
   nulogs=$(ls -l /var/log/dpkg.log.* | wc -l)
   nulogs=$(( $nulogs - $nlogs + 1 ))
   while [ $i -le $nulogs ]
   do
   if [ -e /var/log/dpkg.log.$i ]; then
   cat /var/log/dpkg.log.$i | grep "\ install\ " >> $HOME/pkgtmp.txt
   fi
   i=$(( $i+1 ))

   done

   #next append current log

   cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ " >> $HOME/pkgtmp.txt

   #sort text file by date

   sort -n $HOME/pkgtmp.txt > $HOME/pkginstalls.txt

   rm $HOME/pkgtmp.txt

   # Now displaying the installation details of packages passed as arguments

   for pkg in $@
   do
   echo "--------------------- Installation Details of $pkg ----------------------"
   echo 
   cat $HOME/pkginstalls.txt | grep -i $pkg
   echo
   apt-cache show $pkg | grep "Section" | sort -u
   echo
   done

   exit 0
   ```
2. Make the file executable and copy to `/bin` to use it as a command.

   ```
   chmod a+x pkgdetails && sudo cp pkgdetails /bin/
   ```
3. Now use `pkgdetails` command to get the installation details and section of packages:

   ```
   pkgdetails qbittorrent artha
   ```

**Here is my output:**

```
--------------------- Installation Details of qbittorrent ----------------------

2013-07-24 07:52:27 install qbittorrent <none> 2.9.7-1
2013-07-24 09:11:32 install qbittorrent <none> 3.0.x-0~4366-20130722~precise1
2013-10-19 05:32:27 install qbittorrent <none> 3.0.x-0~4389-20130802~precise1

Section: net
Section: universe/net

--------------------- Installation Details of artha ----------------------

2013-07-11 23:50:16 install artha <none> 1.0.2-1ubuntu1

Section: universe/utils
```

Answer (score 1):

open text editor and paste following with anyname.sh and make it executable with

```
chmod +x  anyname.sh
```

code :

```
#!/bin/bash
#pkginstalls.sh
#creates text file with a list of all packages installed by date

#first append all info from archived logs

i=2
mycount=$(ls -l /var/log/dpkg.log.*.gz | wc -l)
nlogs=$(( $mycount + 1 ))

while [ $i -le $nlogs ]
do
if [ -e /var/log/dpkg.log.$i.gz ]; then
zcat /var/log/dpkg.log.$i.gz | grep "\ install\ " >> $HOME/pkgtmp.txt
fi
i=$(( $i+1 ))

done

#next append all info from unarchived logs

i=1
nulogs=$(ls -l /var/log/dpkg.log.* | wc -l)
nulogs=$(( $nulogs - $nlogs + 1 ))
while [ $i -le $nulogs ]
do
if [ -e /var/log/dpkg.log.$i ]; then
cat /var/log/dpkg.log.$i | grep "\ install\ " >> $HOME/pkgtmp.txt
fi
i=$(( $i+1 ))

done

#next append current log

cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ " >> $HOME/pkgtmp.txt

#sort text file by date

sort -n $HOME/pkgtmp.txt > $HOME/pkginstalls.txt

rm $HOME/pkgtmp.txt

exit 0
```

[credit goes to ubuntu community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ListInstalledPackagesByDate)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The script will have to be modified to get few more details like category.

Answer (score 0):

you must look this site https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto
You will see in here,

> apt-cache show
>
> apt-cache pkgnames

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer (and not enough rep points to make this a comment) - the install log is here:

```
sudo less /var/log/apt/term.log
```

As you seem to be a bit more command line savvy than me, you might try modifying the script here to parse it:

http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2002/08/msg01219.html