# unable to execute /usr/bin/apt-get: Argument list too long

Tags: command-line, apt

I am trying to install a list of software with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install $(cat installed_software.txt)
```

But I receive an error message:

```
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/apt-get: Argument list too long
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks!

(Oh, and I have also tried:

```
xargs -rxa installed_software.txt -- sudo apt-get install --
```

With no success).

Comment: Long lists of packages is a poor use of apt. Instead, simply tell apt the few top-level packages you **really** want, and let apt automagically handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following command (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1027484/790920):

```
sudo apt-get install < installed_software.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of arguments for a command running under `sudo` is rather pathetic. You will find a the maximum number of arguments is much higher if you run the command as root. i.e. do this instead:

```
$ sudo su
# apt-get install $(cat installed_software.txt)
```

Comment: running as root:

apt-get install $(cat installed_software.txt)

Reading package lists... Done
E: Unsupported file /proc given on commandline
E: Unsupported file /proc given on commandline
E: Unsupported file /dev/ given on commandline
E: Unsupported file /usr/share/dict given on commandline
E: Unsupported file /usr/share/dict given on commandline

// I don't get it. Why didn't it work?

Comment: So, I think that would be a problem with the file `installed_software.txt`.

Comment: I guess... Thanks for the help anyway. Gonna try sorting it out.