# Find packages installed directly from a `.deb`

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, deb

This question: [How to list installed package and its details on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389715/how-to-list-installed-package-and-its-details-on-ubuntu) talks about how to see all packages installed through `apt`.

Occasionally I have to install a piece of software directly from a `.deb` file from the publisher. Is there a way to get `dpkg` to show me which packages I installed directly through a `.deb` file using `dpkg` and not through `apt`?

Comment: Since the backend of the **apt** is **dpkg** I think the easiest and a less reliable way  is ```history | grep "dpkg \-i"```.But there are some problems that makes it a little unreliable.Your bash history is limited (unless you raise the limitation), and it's possible for the package to get deleted after you had installed it via dpkg.

Comment: You can use `apt list --installed | grep "local]"`. But this would fail if the package has been updated by APT after installation, for example, VS Code, Google Chrome, etc.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "*installed directly through a .deb file*," How are you "directly" installing .deb files if not using apt or dpkg?

Comment: @user535733 [deb can be an installation source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159094/310780).

Comment: Sorry, when I say "directly through a Deb file" I mean using `dpkg` not `apt`